# Why is $\sum_{n \in \bar{\mathbb{N}}}E(\xi|\mathcal{B_{n}})1_{[\nu=n]}$ $\mathcal{B_{\nu}}$-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

We can prove that if $\nu$ is a stopping time, and $\xi \in L_1$, then

$E(\xi|\mathcal{B_{\nu}})=\sum_{n \in \bar{\mathbb{N}}}E(\xi|\mathcal{B_{n}})1_{[\nu=n]}$.

To prove this, we must prove that the RHS is $\mathcal{B_{\nu}}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{B_{\nu}}=\{B \in \sigma(\cup_n\mathcal{B_{n}}): \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}} \ [\nu=n]\cap B \in \mathcal{B_{n}} \}$.

I think I can easily prove that $1_{[\nu=n]}$ is $\mathcal{B_{\nu}}$-measurable. The problem is $E(\xi|\mathcal{B_{n}})$.

Edit: according to the indications of the user Nulluser, I'm supposed to prove that $E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)1_{[\nu=n]}$ is measurable.

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$,

$E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)1_{[\nu=n]}= \begin{cases} 
      E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n), & [\nu=n] \\
      0 & [\nu\neq n]
   \end{cases}$, which means that

$(E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)1_{[\nu=n]})^{-1}(B)= \begin{cases} 
      E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)^{-1}(B)\cap [\nu=n] , & 0\notin B \\
      [\nu\neq n] &  B=\{0\}\\
      \Omega & \{0\}\subsetneq B
   \end{cases}$.

And in each case we have: $ \begin{cases} E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)^{-1}(B)\cap [\nu=n] \in \mathcal{B}_n \implies E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}\\ [\nu< n]\cup [\nu> n] \in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}\\ \Omega \in \mathcal{B}_{\nu} \end{cases}$

Hence, by definition of $ \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$, we get the previous implication, and so $E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)1_{[\nu=n]}\in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$.

(?)Proof of Theorem of NullUser: 
If $V1_{[\nu=n]}\in \mathcal{B}_{n}$, then we have $(V)^{-1}(B)\cap [\nu=n]\in \mathcal{B}_{n}$, for $0\notin B$. By definition of $ \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$, we get $V^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$ for $0\notin B$ only. However, if we know that $V\in\mathcal{B}_{n}$, then $(V)^{-1}(B)\cap [\nu=n]\in \mathcal{B}_{n}$ for all $B$, and so $V \in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$.

The other direction, it's enough to see that by definition of $\mathcal{B}_{\nu}$, we have $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}}V^{-1}(B)\cap [\nu=N] \in \mathcal{B}_{n}$ and $[\nu< n]\cup [\nu> n], \Omega \in  \mathcal{B}_{n}$, which implies $V1_{[\nu=n]}\in \mathcal{B}_{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Try to prove the following theorem:

> A random variable $V$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}_{\nu}$ if and only if $V 1_{\nu  = n} \in \mathcal{B}_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.

In your case, on the event that $\nu = n$, the sum equals $E(\xi|\mathcal{B}_n)$, which is $\mathcal{B}_n$-measurable, so the theorem applies.

Comment: NullUser, I've edited  my question and included my reasoning following your suggestion. Could you check it if it's okay?

Comment: Well, you should prove the theorem I mentioned, not just use it. Also you haven't applied it correctly. You need to show $V 1_{\nu = n} \in \mathcal{B}_n$ for each $n$, whereas your proof shows $V 1_{\nu = n} \in \mathcal{B}_{\nu}$ for each $n$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's stil correct, right? Also, I've added some more details to prove what your theorem.  However, I think it's not entirely correct(either my proof or your theorem as stated). What do you think?